# how to get JQeasy Slide panels to not overlap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery slide found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150227082803/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-slide-panel-plugin
The problem I am having is that if you have multiple triggers and panels the panels will overlap each other rather then leave the panel and open the new panel.

Now I am using the "clickOutsideToClose: true" function which does work but not if you click another tab directly. Here is the script in use:

```
<script>
$('#panel1').slidePanel({
    triggerName: '#trigger1',
    position: 'fixed',
    triggerTopPos: '0px',
    panelTopPos: '0px',
    panelOpacity:  1,  
    clickOutsideToClose: true
});

$('#panel2').slidePanel({
    triggerName: '#trigger2',
    position: 'fixed',
    triggerTopPos: '55px',
    panelTopPos: '0px',
    panelOpacity:  1,  
    clickOutsideToClose: true
});
</script>
```

The code is being used here in the top left corner so you can test and see what I mean: http://w11.zetaboards.com/SWGTest/index/

Basically I just want it so the panel's don't overlay each other and when you click on another trigger and one is already active the already active one will close and the new one will open.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is z-index.

Both z-index are 100.

Keep like this if click on panel1, the panel1 z-index to be 105 and panel2 z-index to be 100. If click on panel2, the panel2 z-index to be 105 and panel1 z-index to be 100.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do that? I understand that I need the z-indexs to change on click but how do I get the code to do that. Will I need to add some sort of javascript that changes the z-index for each panel depending on which trigger I click? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: EDIT: got it working, your answer led to my salvation. Thanks kindly sir.